# Merge table rows with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table that have same values for each person, so I need to merge those rows for that person with same values. In some cases all rows with same value are merging but they are repeated with same values. In some other cases courses with same name are merged and this not right as I mentioned before only same values for one person should merge,
(so sorry for my bad English, don't know how to explain this I hope snippet show you enough)
 Any solution for this?

```js
function groupTable($rows, startIndex, total) {
  if (total === 0) {
    return;
  }
  var i, currentIndex = startIndex,
    count = 1,
    lst = [];
  var tds = $rows.find('td:eq(' + currentIndex + ')');
  var ctrl = $(tds[0]);
  lst.push($rows[0]);
  for (i = 1; i <= tds.length; i++) {
    if (ctrl.attr("id") == $(tds[i]).attr("id")) {
      count++;
      $(tds[i]).addClass('deleted');
      lst.push($rows[i]);

    } else {
      if (count > 1) {
        ctrl.attr('rowspan', count);
        groupTable($(lst), startIndex + 1, total - 1)
      }
      count = 1;
      lst = [];
      ctrl = $(tds[i]);
      lst.push($rows[i]);
    }
  }
}
groupTable($('#myTable tr:has(td)'), 0, 14);
$('#myTable .deleted').remove();
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped border-top table-bordered" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr id="th1" style="background:#d3d3d3 ;">
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
      <th>Teacher</th>
      <th>Curse</th>
      <th colspan="3">Morning</th>
      <th colspan="3">Evening</th>
      <th colspan="2" style="font-size: 12px;">Weekly hour</th>

      <th>sum</th>
      <th>-</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="th2">
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>theory</th>
      <th>Practical</th>
      <th>free</th>
      <th>theory</th>
      <th>Practical</th>
      <th>free</th>
      <th>Morning</th>
      <th>Evening</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="details_view">
    <tr id="p">
      <td id="id7" class "ids"="" data-id="ids">1</td>
      <td id="prof7">Mr</td>
      <td id="prof7">John Doe</td>
      <td id="prof7" style="font-size: 12px;">Electric</td>
      <td id="prof7" data-time="morning_theory" data-crs="Electric" data-prof="John Doe">0</td>
      <td id="prof7" data-time="morning_practical" data-crs="Electric" data-prof="John Doe">18</td>
      <td id="prof7" data-time="morning_free" data-crs="Electric" data-prof="John Doe">12</td>
      <td id="prof7" data-time="evening_theory" data-crs="Electric" data-prof="John Doe">0</td>
      <td id="prof7" data-time="evening_practical" data-crs="Electric" data-prof="John Doe">0</td>
      <td id="prof7" data-time="evening_free" data-crs="Electric" data-prof="John Doe">0</td>
      <td id="sob7" style="background:#d3d3d3 ;">30</td>
      <td id="asr7" style="background:#d3d3d3 ;">0</td>
      <td id="prof7">30</td>
      <td id="prof7" style="width: 160px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="p">
      <td id="id7" class "ids"="" data-id="ids">2</td>
      <td id="prof7">Mr</td>
      <td id="prof7">John Doe</td>
      <td id="prof7" style="font-size: 12px;">course2</td>
      <td id="prof7" data-time="morning_theory" data-crs="course2" data-prof="John Doe">0</td>
      <td id="prof7" data-time="morning_practical" data-crs="course2" data-prof="John Doe">18</td>
      <td id="prof7" data-time="morning_free" data-crs="course2" data-prof="John Doe">12</td>
      <td id="prof7" data-time="evening_theory" data-crs="course2" data-prof="John Doe">0</td>
      <td id="prof7" data-time="evening_practical" data-crs="course2" data-prof="John Doe">0</td>
      <td id="prof7" data-time="evening_free" data-crs="course2" data-prof="John Doe">0</td>
      <td id="sob7" style="background:#d3d3d3 ;">30</td>
      <td id="asr7" style="background:#d3d3d3 ;">0</td>
      <td id="prof7">30</td>
      <td id="prof7" style="width: 160px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="p">
      <td id="id7" class "ids"="" data-id="ids">3</td>
      <td id="prof7">Mr</td>
      <td id="prof7">John Doe</td>
      <td id="prof7" style="font-size: 12px;">course2</td>
      <td id="prof7" data-time="morning_theory" data-crs="course2" data-prof="John Doe">0</td>
      <td id="prof7" data-time="morning_practical" data-crs="course2" data-prof="John Doe">18</td>
      <td id="prof7" data-time="morning_free" data-crs="course2" data-prof="John Doe">12</td>
      <td id="prof7" data-time="evening_theory" data-crs="course2" data-prof="John Doe">0</td>
      <td id="prof7" data-time="evening_practical" data-crs="course2" data-prof="John Doe">0</td>
      <td id="prof7" data-time="evening_free" data-crs="course2" data-prof="John Doe">0</td>
      <td id="sob7" style="background:#d3d3d3 ;">30</td>
      <td id="asr7" style="background:#d3d3d3 ;">0</td>
      <td id="prof7">۳۰</td>
      <td id="prof7" style="width: 160px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="p">
      <td id="id30" class "ids"="" data-id="ids">4</td>
      <td id="prof30">Mr</td>
      <td id="prof30">Robert Anderson</td>
      <td id="prof12" style="font-size: 12px;">Course2 </td>
      <td id="prof12" data-time="morning_theory" data-crs="Course2" data-prof="Robert Anderson">0</td>
      <td id="prof12" data-time="morning_practical" data-crs="Course2" data-prof="Robert Anderson">0</td>
      <td id="prof12" data-time="morning_free" data-crs="Course2" data-prof="Robert Anderson">0</td>
      <td id="prof12" data-time="evening_theory" data-crs="Course2" data-prof="Robert Anderson">0</td>
      <td id="prof12" data-time="evening_practical" data-crs="Course2" data-prof="Robert Anderson">6</td>
      <td id="prof12" data-time="evening_free" data-crs="Course2" data-prof="Robert Anderson">0</td>
      <td id="sob12" style="background:#d3d3d3 ;">0</td>
      <td id="asr12" style="background:#d3d3d3 ;">6</td>
      <td id="prof12">6</td>
      <td id="prof12" style="width: 160px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="p">
      <td id="id6" class "ids"="" data-id="ids">5</td>
      <td id="prof6">Mr</td>
      <td id="prof6">Jack Hulk</td>
      <td id="prof5" style="font-size: 12px;">Course3</td>
      <td id="prof5" data-time="morning_theory" data-crs="Course3" data-prof="Jack Hulk">8</td>
      <td id="prof5" data-time="morning_practical" data-crs="Course3" data-prof="Jack Hulk">12</td>
      <td id="prof5" data-time="morning_free" data-crs="Course3" data-prof="Jack Hulk">2</td>
      <td id="prof5" data-time="evening_theory" data-crs="Course3" data-prof="Jack Hulk">2</td>
      <td id="prof5" data-time="evening_practical" data-crs="Course3" data-prof="Jack Hulk">4</td>
      <td id="prof5" data-time="evening_free" data-crs="Course3" data-prof="Jack Hulk">18</td>
      <td id="sob5" style="background:#d3d3d3 ;">22</td>
      <td id="asr5" style="background:#d3d3d3 ;">24</td>
      <td id="prof5">46</td>
      <td id="prof5" style="width: 160px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="p">
      <td id="id6" class "ids"="" data-id="ids">6</td>
      <td id="prof6">Mr</td>
      <td id="prof6">Jack Hulk</td>
      <td id="prof5" style="font-size: 12px;">Course3</td>
      <td id="prof5" data-time="morning_theory" data-crs="Course3" data-prof="Jack Hulk">8</td>
      <td id="prof5" data-time="morning_practical" data-crs="Course3" data-prof="Jack Hulk">12</td>
      <td id="prof5" data-time="morning_free" data-crs="Course3" data-prof="Jack Hulk">2</td>
      <td id="prof5" data-time="evening_theory" data-crs="Course3" data-prof="Jack Hulk">2</td>
      <td id="prof5" data-time="evening_practical" data-crs="Course3" data-prof="Jack Hulk">4</td>
      <td id="prof5" data-time="evening_free" data-crs="Course3" data-prof="Jack Hulk">18</td>
      <td id="sob5" style="background:#d3d3d3 ;">22</td>
      <td id="asr5" style="background:#d3d3d3 ;">24</td>
      <td id="prof5">46</td>
      <td id="prof5" style="width: 160px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="p">
      <td id="id6" class "ids"="" data-id="ids">7</td>
      <td id="prof6">Mr</td>
      <td id="prof6">Jack Hulk</td>
      <td id="prof5" style="font-size: 12px;">Course3</td>
      <td id="prof5" data-time="morning_theory" data-crs="Course3" data-prof="Jack Hulk">8</td>
      <td id="prof5" data-time="morning_practical" data-crs="Course3" data-prof="Jack Hulk">12</td>
      <td id="prof5" data-time="morning_free" data-crs="Course3" data-prof="Jack Hulk">2</td>
      <td id="prof5" data-time="evening_theory" data-crs="Course3" data-prof="Jack Hulk">2</td>
      <td id="prof5" data-time="evening_practical" data-crs="Course3" data-prof="Jack Hulk">4</td>
      <td id="prof5" data-time="evening_free" data-crs="Course3" data-prof="Jack Hulk">18</td>
      <td id="sob5" style="background:#d3d3d3 ;">22</td>
      <td id="asr5" style="background:#d3d3d3 ;">24</td>
      <td id="prof5">46</td>
      <td id="prof5" style="width: 160px;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: But the snippet example seems to give the right output. Could you instead give a snippet example where it goes wrong? If the snippet output is wrong, please add the table that you expect as output.

Comment: This snippet already has wrong result. look at "Mr John Doe" in html code. He has 2 different courses but in results its not shown.

Comment: So you want only rows to be removed when they are *completely* the same? Or only when some columns are the same?

Comment: I want all rows for one person with same value to be merged.

Comment: What is "with same value"? Which value(s)? All rows have at least one cell different. For instance, the first cell (the "#" column) is always different in your example. Others have a different value in the "sum" column (like row 2 and 3).... It is not clear what you mean with "with same value".

Comment: Look at html source. For example John Doe has "course2" in two rows with different hours. Sum of this hour will shown in both two rows and they have same value now. sow one of them get ".deleted" class so it will be hidden. You just need to look at html source and then results.

Comment: I don't understand this question. I am moving on. Maybe someone else can help you.